# RecyclerView doesn't respect translation when recycling views

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-recyclerview

Im playing with `RecyclerView` right now and stumbled upon the following problem. When RecyclerView's `LinearLayoutManager` makes a decision about whether view went off screen (so it can be recycler) it doesn't take into account view's `translationY`.

So essentially, when I scroll up and I have views with positive `translationY`, `LinearLayoutManager` thinks that view is off screen, but in fact, it is still visible (because it is translated down).

I noticed that the way `LinearLayoutManager` makes this decision - is by looking at `getDecoratedBottom(View)`, so I tried to override `getDecoratedBottom(View)` to also include translation. Unfortunately, it messes up layout completely - this method is also used when we layout new items, so new items get extra translation (on top of existing one)..

Is there an easy way to tell `LinearLayoutManager` to look at `translation` attribute when it makes a decision about recycling view w/o re-implementing `LayoutManager` from scratch?

Comment: Have you found a solution for the problem?

Comment: @ZakharovRoman yeah... Forked LinearLayoutManager implementation and modified its logic a bit to also include translation. But nothing 'out of the box' could actually solve the issue.

Comment: ok, I will try. thanks

Answer (score 0):

May be it will be helpfull to somebody, I've found a solution.

Firstly I tried to use Translate animation with no luck.
But then, I just created a new class extending `ItemDecoration`. Then overridden `getItemOffsets()` and set proper offset on Rect. LayoutManager calculates this offsets successfully. Achieved result is on the attached image.

[image]

Comment: well, not sure its gonna work in my case since Im changing translation on each frame. Dont really know implications of changing decoration offset so often.